# Including Attachment in Message Board Email Notification

Tags: smtp, liferay

I would like to include any/all attachments posted in a thread on my Message Board to  be sent via email to those subscribed to the thread. Currently it does not seem Liferay does this by default - is there any standard way to implement this?